# Detect when computer goes into sleep mode

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Is it possible in Java to detect when the computer goes into sleep mode? I've already tried to count seconds with `Thread.sleep(1000)` but it seems as if it would continue counting in sleep mode.

Comment: Can you clarify, "... but it seems as if it would continue counting in sleep mode"? Did you do a test and determine this? Or is this just a guess? If you did a test, can you provide the Java code and the steps you took to put your test machine to sleep?

Comment: Also, do you want to be signaled as the computer is going to sleep? Or to be able to detect a sleep upon awakening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213127/detect-os-sleep-and-wake-up-events-in-java

Comment: Using Thread.sleep(1000) you will notice your seconds count start to lag over an extended period. Instead you should use java.util.Timer

Comment: @erickson i've written a program to track the running time of a device by adding one second every second. But if I turn my device into sleep mode, and wake it up 20s later, it doesn't continue where I put it into sleep mode

Comment: @eli2003 If you want to know how much time has passed, including time spent sleeping, simply subtract the start time from the current time (i.e., `System.currentTImeMillis() - start`). If you want to skip time spent sleeping, then setting a recurring timer that increments a counter (sounds like what you have implemented) is the right approach: it will not be incremented while asleep. You can use both approaches to detect a discrepancy that indicates a sleep has occurred.